# UNION after ORDER BY and LIMIT

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, union

My goal is to execute two different  queries and then combine them.
My code is:

```
SELECT * FROM some tables WHERE ... ORDER BY field1 LIMIT 0,1 
UNION   
SELECT * FROM some tables WHERE ...
```

I get the following error:

> #1221 - Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY

It is important that ORDER BY is only for the first query. How can I perform this task?

Comment: Read this [tutorial](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/sql-union-mysql.aspx)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can use parenthesis to allow the use of `ORDER`/`LIMIT` on individual queries:

```
(SELECT * FROM some tables WHERE ... ORDER BY field1 LIMIT 0, 1)
UNION   
(SELECT * FROM some tables WHERE ...)
ORDER BY 1   /* optional -- applies to the UNIONed result */
LIMIT 0, 100 /* optional -- applies to the UNIONed result */
```

Comment: it didnt work for me http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1004382/maintain-order-of-two-queries-after-union

Answer (score 11):

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM some tables WHERE ... ORDER BY field1 LIMIT 0,1) x
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM some tables WHERE ...
```

Note the use of `UNION ALL`:

- `UNION` removes duplicate rows from the result set and the DB orders *all* the rows before doing this (so the entire result set is sorted)
- `UNION ALL` preserves both order and duplicates

Answer (score 4):

just put everything in round brackets:

```
(SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY datetime  )
UNION   
(SELECT * FROM table2 ORDER BY datetime DESC)
```

Comment: syntax error... you need to select from the aliased (bracketed) select

Comment: I checked and got the error. Maybe I need to upgrade my mysql. Sorry!

Answer (score 2):

```
(SELECT user_id AS id FROM tbl_user)
UNION
(SELECT address_id AS id FROM tbl_address)
ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 10
```